# exporting multiple access tables to single XML

Tags: xml, ms-access, vba

I have multiple Microsoft Access tables that I want exported into a single XML file.  How do I manipulate the order and hierarchy of the tables into the XML structure that I want?  In essence, I want to be able to reverse the import XML process, which automatically breaks down the data into multiple tables.  I can use VBA, SQL, and any built-in export function at my disposal.

Answer (score 5):

I use the attached to produce a 3 million line nested xml in about five minutes.

There are two key items,

1) a simple piece of VB,

```
Public Function Export_ListingData()

    Dim objOtherTbls As AdditionalData

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandle
    Set objOtherTbls = Application.CreateAdditionalData
    objOtherTbls.Add "ro_address"
    objOtherTbls.Add "ro_buildingDetails"
    objOtherTbls.Add "ro_businessDetails"
    objOtherTbls.Add "ro_businessExtras"
    objOtherTbls.Add "ro_businessExtrasAccounts"
    objOtherTbls.Add "ro_businessExtrasAccom"
    objOtherTbls.Add "ro_businessExtrasAccom2"

    Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportTable, _
                DataSource:="ro_business", _
                DataTarget:="C:\Users\Steve\Documents\Conversions\ListData.xml", _
                AdditionalData:=objOtherTbls
Exit_Here:
        MsgBox "Export_ListingData completed"
        Exit Function
ErrorHandle:
        MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
        Resume Exit_Here
End Function
```

2) Linking the tables in relationship manager using joins from primary to FOREIGN keys.

If there are no relationships the code will produce a sequential xml file, if there are
relationships between primary keys you will get a 31532 error and the data export will fail.

Answer (score 3):

here is the solution via VBA:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff193212.aspx

create a from and put a button on it. right click on the button and choose "build event" and past the following code:

```
Dim objOtherTbls As AdditionalData


Set objOtherTbls = Application.CreateAdditionalData

'Identify the tables or querys to export
objOtherTbls.Add "internet"
objOtherTbls.Add "mokaleme"

'Here is where the export takes place
Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportTable, _
DataSource:="internet", _
DataTarget:="C:\myxml.xml", _
AdditionalData:=objOtherTbls

MsgBox "Export operation completed successfully."
```

you have to type the name of your tables here and between quotations:

```
   objOtherTbls.Add "internet"
    objOtherTbls.Add "mokaleme"

    DataSource:="internet"
```